# Disable SSHd UseDNS for particular client

Tags: domain-name-system, ssh

I have two machines, both with permanent IP addresses.  One machine (the Client) needs to frequently access the other (the Server) using SSH.  This works fine, however the server is configured with `UseDNS yes`.  The along the way something does not map back to what it should, and my logs keep getting filled with "POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT".

I can prevent this by turning off UseDNS, but I think would rather do it selectively for just this one client that I know is safe.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is possible, given how UseDNS kicks into action before the user has any chance to authentify.

It is probably easier to fix name resolution. If DNS is out of your control, you could add an entry to `/etc/hosts`, that should fix the problem.